# Vim - is it possible to show Intro instead of creating a [No Name] file when the buffer list is empty?

Tags: vim, neovim

I never use `[No Name]` buffers to create a file. If I need to create a file I use `:e <file-path>`.

With that being said, the default behaviour of opening an empty buffer is annoying. I often end up with several empty buffers that I don't need. I would much prefer to have the Intro screen display if all of my buffers are closed.

Is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm confused. When you open vim to a new blank buffer, you deliberately open another new blank buffer to save as a new file? Instead of just creating a file from the first buffer that vim opens? But why? How do you end up with any empty buffers? Are you under the impression that `[no name]` buffers are something unique? They're just buffers without a name. Give them a name.

Comment: Okay, let me try again. I have no use for automatically created unnamed buffers. I find their creation irritating as when I need a new buffer I can create one using `e:` or `:new`, etc. When I am closing all of my open named buffers I would rather have the Intro screen display when there are no more buffers rather than create a new unnamed buffer.

Comment: What is automatically creating blank buffers? If you open vim with just `vim` and no argument, it will open to a single unnamed blank buffer. As far as I know, that is the only `[no name]` buffer that it will create without doing `:new` or something similar. And vim will not re-open unmodified buffers when you quit other windows. If you have one window open and do `:q`, it should not open a blank buffer. Also, are you aware that `:e newfile` and then `:w` is the same as doing `:w newfile` in the blank buffer? Why the extra step of `:e` instead of just doing `:w newfile` in the unnamed buffer?

Comment: If I have a number of named buffers open and I close them all I will be left with a blank buffer.

Comment: In that case, the blank buffer was probably open the whole time in a window. If you have only a single window remaining and do `:q`, vim should exit, unless that unnamed buffer was modified and unsaved, although that would give you a warning saying so. Are you saying that if you have only one window open and attempt to close it, an unnamed blank buffer takes its place? Maybe you could describe exactly what happens in better detail. Steps to reproduce even.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would much prefer to have the Intro screen display if all of my buffers are closed.

`:intro` is not buffer. It's on-screen message drawn over some buffer. By design Vim always has at least one buffer, one window and one tab active. If you quit the last window with `:q` then Vim also quits.

> I often end up with several empty buffers that I don't need.

Every buffer is created and/or loaded because of your actions. For example, if Vim is started simply as `vim` it has to create an empty buffer; if `vim filename` then it does not. The same applies to `:new` vs. `:new filename`, `:tabedit` vs. `:tabedit filename` etc.etc.

Answer (score 4):

Vim always has **at least one buffer**, displayed in **at least one window**, displayed in **at least one tab page**. There is simply no way around that. No buffer, no Vim.

When you start Vim with a filename:

```
$ vim filename
```

it creates a buffer named after `filename` with the content of `filename`, which satisfies the conditions above so there is no need for creating an empty `[No Name]` buffer.

When you start Vim without a filename:

```
$ vim
```

it *must* create a buffer to satisfy the conditions above so it creates an empty `[No Name]` buffer. Having at least one buffer, empty or not, named or not, is an absolute prerequisite for Vim to actually run.

If you are not OK with that, just do `$ vim filename` or `$ vim directoryname` instead of starting an empty session. Besides, "let's start Vim and figure out what to do afterward" sounds weird compared to "let's edit `filename` in Vim".